# strange: android EditText cannot show softkeyboard(it quickly hide)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a normal EditText View,when click on it,then the softkeyboard show,
but the strange problem is its hide quicklly. the layout code:
that'a all

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pick_school_bitmap_bg"
 >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/customer_action_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_action_bar_repeat"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/pick_school_item_background"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/home_as_up_indicator"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/pick_school_ic_menu_search"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_search_school"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/pick_school_textfield_activated"
        android:hint="@string/pick_school_search_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
         />

</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customer_action_bar"
    layout="@layout/pick_school_search_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

it's too strange that,the softkeyboard show and quickly disappear:
the log info was:

09-16 17:55:08.472: D/InputMethodManager(31721): onInputShownChanged: true

09-16 17:55:08.527: D/InputMethodManager(31721): onInputShownChanged: false

09-16 17:55:09.282: D/InputMethodManager(31721): onInputShownChanged: true

09-16 17:55:09.322: D/InputMethodManager(31721): onInputShownChanged: false

09-16 17:55:09.522: D/InputMethodManager(31721): onInputShownChanged: true

Comment: share your layoutcode for edittext

Comment: have update layout code now

Comment: I tried your layout without the including ¸`pick_school_search_view´ and your color and images. its working fine the Keyboard appears while clicking on the view and stays until back key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

To display soft keyBoard. Can you please try with this.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)            
    Context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),      
    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

One more thing you can add onEditTextFocusable() manually force the keyboard to visiable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but  I tried ,it not work.thie softkeyboad will display when the EditText get focus,but it disapear quickly.

Comment: :I once tried stateVisible in windowSoftInputMode,but it does not solve my problem ,it just show softkeyboard when activity start.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line in Manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Set Focus on edittext, so that keyboard will pop up

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/idEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="24sp" >

<requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Try in java code

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(edittext, 0);
```

Comment: thank you,And I tried it,But this can not solve my problem. my probem is the softkeyboard show and quickly disapper.